# Setting $scope.$watch on each element in an array

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to figure out how to set a `$scope.$watch` on each element in an array. I only care about certain attributes of each element.

In my example, each `rental_date` object has three attributes: `date`, `start_time`, and `stop_time`. Whenever the `start_time` is changed, I want the `stop_time` to be set to 2 hours after the `start_time`.

The `$ngResource` call (using *Angular 1.1.5*):

```
Agreement.show( 
  id: 5 
).$then ((success) ->
  $scope.agreement = success.data.agreement

  # returns an array of rental dates
  $scope.rental_dates = success.data.rental_dates

  # $watch goes here
```

Here are the four variations of the `$watch` function I tried:

#### 1:

```
angular.forEach $scope.rental_dates, (date, pos) ->
  $scope.$watch date.start_time, ((newval, oldval) ->
    $log.info 'watch changed'
    $log.info newval
    $log.info oldval
  ), true
```

#### 2:

```
angular.forEach $scope.rental_dates, (date, pos) ->
  $scope.$watch $scope.rental_dates[pos].start_time, ((newval, oldval) ->
    $log.info 'watch changed'
    $log.info newval
    $log.info oldval
  ), true
```

#### 3:

```
angular.forEach $scope.rental_dates, (date, pos) ->
  $scope.$watch 'rental_dates[pos].start_time', ((newval, oldval) ->
    # also tried '$scope.rental_dates[pos].start_time'

    $log.info 'watch changed'
    $log.info newval
    $log.info oldval
  ), true
```

#### 4:

This does work, but, at the moment, I can't think of an elegant solution to access only the values I care about `$watch`ing instead of the whole array.

```
$scope.$watch 'rental_dates', ((newval, oldval) ->
  $log.info 'watch changed'
  $log.info newval
  $log.info oldval
), true
```

Has anybody done something similar in their own projects?

Comment: How does the `start_time` change in your code ? Is it a user action or at least something you can track ? For something like this, if possible, I'd try to watch an array made with the ids of the values changed, then you watch this array instead of the whole data (but it needs to change the part of your code that modifies the `start_time`)

Comment: Both the `start_time` and `stop_time` are bound to *Angular UI*'s `timepicker` directive. Whenever the user changes the `start_time`, I want the `stop_time` to be set to two hours afterwards.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I am assuming you're somehow using ng-repeat to generate UI elements for each entry of the array? Assign an ng-controller to each of these UI elements. The controller will be instantiated for each array element. Inside that controller, use $watch.

```
<div ng-repeat="rentalDate in rental_dates" ng-controller="RentalDateController">
</div>
```

And then in your controller code:

```
angular.module(...).controller('RentalDateController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.$watch('rentalDate.start_time', function (startTime) {
        ...
    });
});
```

Here is a little example: http://plnkr.co/edit/lhJ3MbULmahzdehCxVeM?p=preview

Comment: This works for me as well. Thank you. I have a few questions: 1) How can I tell what variables the controller inherits? Logging out the $scope to the console didn't show what variables I can play with. 2) Do you have any resources that explains angular inheritance (I think that is the concept here) for ng-controllers? Thanks again.

Comment: So, the watch function works, but if I attempt to log to the console the rental_date's stop time, the console throws me an error stating `ReferenceError: rental_date is not defined`. I can access the stop time using `$scope.$parent.rental_date.stop_time` but this doesn't seem very elegant.

Comment: So I have a lot to learn about how Angular/Javascript handles inheritance. `$scope.rental_date` works the same as `$scope.$parent.rental_date`.

Comment: $scope inheritance works similar to JavaScript's prototype chain inheritance: if a property or method is not found in the current scope, then the parent scope is checked, and so on. However, if you set a property in the current scope, then you're overwriting that property, hiding the parent scope's value. There is a Batarang extension for Chrome that might help you with debugging nested scopes.

Comment: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2450-using-ngcontroller-with-ngrepeat-in-angularjs.htm has a good example with accessing the properties or methods from the parent scope.

Comment: There is no reason you should assume that we are using `ng-repeat` at all. Assume that I have exactly what the question suggested: a JSON data-model and a `$watch`, that's all. How do you apply a `$watch` to each index of an array programmatically using strictly JavaScript. I feel like you did not answer this question.

Comment: @WebWanderer It might not be the answer to the literal question, it is however the solution to the underlying problem. There is no need for $watching for user changes without creating UI elements.

Comment: "There is no need for $watching for user changes without creating UI elements." - vsp.  This is indeed NOT true my friend. I'm sorry, but there are MANY interesting and practical uses for the $watch.

Comment: And yes, you did solve the solution, yet understand that many times a user will create an example problem to ask if a solution can be reached in a very specific way. There are many ways to solve a problem, and unless the question is very specific (as this one was, so you do win here) then the odds are that the OP thought of your other solutions already. If the OP asks for a solution to be done in a very specific manner (which our OP here didn't really do), try and stay in their bounds, odds are they just want food for thought, not a new pair of shoes.

Comment: This isn't really the place for my point, yet I felt as if this topic had arisen here and I have very strong opinions on it. Our OP had tried multiple solutions and was asking for the best one. I am glad that your solution worked for our OP, as it is a very good one, yet the odds of it matching our OP's structure at the time of the post were very low, and that is what rubbed me the wrong way about it. Good solution though.

Comment: @WebWanderer Wow what a grand display that was! vsp's solution is what I was looking for as well.

Answer (score 8):

I think solution number 3 will work if you change the first `$watch` argument to: `'rental_dates['+pos+'].start_time'` ([$watch](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope#%24watch) takes an angular expression as the first parameter, and pos isn't part of your scope).

(While this should work, I think this won't be really efficient. Maybe you should look into updating both start_time and stop_time at the same time instead of watching for changes on all the start times.)

Comment: Hooray! This worked. Could you expound your last statement a bit more? I should explain myself as well: the `start_time` is bound to the the *Angular UI* `timepicker` directive. So, whenever a user changes the `start_time`, the `stop_time` is automatically set to two hours afterwards.

Comment: I don't know angularUI, but if it works like standard input tags, you should have some kind of "onChange" callback that you could use to update the stop_value when the start_value changes. Another solution would be to create a directive "updateRentalTime" that handles the editing of both values.

Comment: The beauty of AngularJS is that you don't need to build directives all the time if you don't want to reuse the code. If the code needed to be reusable, you could wrap my solution into a directive.

Comment: onChange UI event handlers are discouraged in AngularJS. The model should be the record of the current state of your application. Let the UI elements write the user changes into the model, then react on model changes.

Comment: @vsp, I'm still trying to wrap my head around your last comment. The client wants the `stop_time` to automatically update whenever the `start_time` is changed. Each `timepicker` directive has an `ng-model` attached: `rental_date.start_time`. I was using `$scope.$watch` to say, 'when this is changed, update that'. Is this not the right way?

Comment: Yann was suggesting using the `<input>`'s [onChange](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp) event. I am however suggesting exactly what you are describing: wait for the `timepicker` to update the model via data binding, and then react on model changes.

Comment: Thank you for answering the question in the method it was asked. There is no reason to assume that a template is being used here. This is the correct answer.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to watch on a specific field in an object that is part of a collection and if you have the collection's items iterated in the view by ng-repeat and if you have the field to be watched bound to a control that can have ng-change, you can always handle the watching aspect using the ng-change handler. eg:

```
 <div ng-repeat="binding in bindings track by $index">
     <input ng-model="binding" ng-change="changed(binding)">
 </div>
```

and in js:

```
 scope.changed = function(binding){
      .....
 }
```

Comment: This solution bypass the complexity of the previous solutions.