# watching expressions in angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, watch

Is it possible to watch an ng-repeat expression? I am working with live data and I want to watch the expression value for changes. What is the best way to do this. Maybe a better questions is how watch key on an array of objects. here is my code as well

```
//MY CONTROLLER//
        $http.get('myJsonUrl')
                .then(function (person) {
                    $scope.personInfo = person.data;
                    $scope.val = person.data.val <--not working

                    console.log('returnedData', $scope.personInfo, $scope.val);
                });

HTML
 <table>
    <tr ng-repeat ='data in personInfo" >
    <td>{{data.val}}</td>  <--I want to watch this in scope
    </tr>
 </table>
```

Comment: you could use `track by` like `<tr ng-repeat ='data in personInfo track by data.val" >` to re-render `ng-repeat` when `data.val` changed.

Comment: Are you saying that the ng-repeat attribute will change? or that the value of $scope.personInfo will change? If it's $scope.personInfo, it should be automatically watching this for you already

Comment: The data model will change, yes angular does watch and reflect this but i only on a page refresh. I need the model to update live. I can place a watcher on it with $watch but am not sure how to access that prop on all objs. while $scope.val comes back as undefined

Answer (score 0):

You can instantiate a new controller (and watch) for every row in the ng-repeat.

```
<table>
  <tr ng-repeat ="data in personInfo" ng-controller="PersonInfoController">
  <td>{{data.val}}</td>  <--I want to watch this in scope
</tr>
```

```
angular.module(...).controller('PersonInfoController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.$watch('data.val', function (n, o) {
        ...
        // from here you can also access your parent controller e.g.
        $scope.someParentMethod(n);
    });
});
```

based on the answer found here [Setting $scope.$watch on each element in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18106649/setting-scope-watch-on-each-element-in-an-array)